# ASP.Net Core at AWS EBS - write permissions and .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

We have deployed ASP.Net Core app on AWS EBS and have problem with writing files on it.

> Access to the path `C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\App_Data\file.txt` is denied

I added `.ebextensions\[app_name].config` but it did nothing

```
{
    "container_commands": {
        "01": {
            "command": "icacls \"C:/inetpub/AspNetCoreWebApps/app/App_Data\" /grant DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)"
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this is permission problem because when I RDP to machine and changed permission manually it solved problem. I would like to it during deploy using `.ebextensions\[app_name].config`

Comment: the ebextension file is yaml - make sure it is not tab delimited and is encoded in UTF-8. Also I'm assuming your extension file is not literally called [app_name].config.

Comment: Name off app is this same like here https://i.imgur.com/kEOGvCa.png also this same like in `aws-beanstalk-config.txt` => `Application.Name`

Comment: just call it init.config and check the spacing and encoding.

Comment: `.ebextensions\[app_name].config` run before deploy and during deploy folder was recreated - that why it was not working. I fixed it by adding `postInstall` Power Shell script into `aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json`

Comment: I cannot create that config file as, it takes it as xml file and I can not put json/yaml content inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ebextensions\[app_name].config` run before deploy and during deploy folder was recreated - that why it was not working. I fixed it by adding `postInstall` Power Shell script into `aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json`:

```
"scripts": {
      "postInstall": {
        "file": "SetupScripts/PostInstallSetup.ps1"
      }
```

```
# # PostInstallSetup.ps1 #
$SharePath = "C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\App_Data"
$Acl = Get-ACL $SharePath
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DefaultAppPool","full","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","none","Allow")
$Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $SharePath $Acl
```

Comment: Can you share the content of SetupScripts/PostInstallSetup.ps1?

Comment: `#
# PostInstallSetup.ps1
#
$sharepath = "C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\App_Data"
$Acl = Get-ACL $SharePath
$AccessRule= New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DefaultAppPool","full","ContainerInherit,Objectinherit","none","Allow")
$Acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
Set-Acl $SharePath $Acl`