# Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache' is denied. Amazon AWS Beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, umbraco7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to setup an Umbraco website on Amazon AWS Beanstalk using the AWS Toolkit for Visual studio 2017, I have added the .ebextensions folder and inside my config file

```
{
"containercommands": {
"01-changeperm": {
"command": "icacls \"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/App_Data\" /grant IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)"
}
}
}
```

I have also tried **DefaultAppPool** instead of **IIS_IUSRS** as per this post [How can I set folder permissions for elastic beanstalk windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047587/how-can-i-set-folder-permissions-for-elastic-beanstalk-windows-application/27393459#27393459) and I have also tried

```
commands:
  create_default_website_folder:
    command: if not exist "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" mkdir "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
  update_iis_user_permissions:
    command: Icacls.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" /grant IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)F
```

from this post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/run-umbraco-cms-with-flexible-load-balancing-on-aws/ along with many other post, but none work, does anyone know what else I need to do as I'm constantly getting the following error.

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache' is
>   denied.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766991/asp-net-core-at-aws-ebs-write-permissions-and-ebextensions

Answer (score 2):

You can visit this page to see what Umbraco needs: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/permissions

Essentially all of these need modify permissions to all of the folders in your umbraco installation:

- IUSR
- IIS_IUSRS
- IIS apppool\[appoolname]

Answer (score 0):

Wow! your post is really help me (and  https://thedeveloperspace.com/granting-write-access-to-asp-net-apps-hosted-on-aws-beanstalk/  and [ASP.Net Core at AWS EBS - write permissions and .ebextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766991/asp-net-core-at-aws-ebs-write-permissions-and-ebextensions) )

In my scenario my local folder for temp files is at

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Temp

So I reedit your command to

```
commands:
  create_default_website_folder:
    command: if not exist "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Temp" mkdir "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Temp"
container_commands:
  01storage_permissions:
    command: "icacls C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Temp /grant DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)F"
```

Then I have permission to use my target folder thanks for the mkdir  command.

Becuase your Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache' is denied.
May be your config must be specific folder like this ?

```
commands:
  create_default_website_folder:
    command: if not exist "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache" mkdir "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache"
  update_iis_user_permissions:
    command: Icacls.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache" /grant IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)F
```